# How to use Promise with redux and socket.io

Tags: node.js, websocket, redux, react-redux

I am a newbie to react-redux. I am stuck at situation wherein i emit an action to the server. The server in turn makes a third party API request which return a promise. My server.js file for handling socket connection in the server looks like the following

```
import Server from 'socket.io';

export default function startServer(store) {
    const io = new Server().attach(8090);

    store.subscribe(
        () =>io.emit('curr_news', store.getState().toJS()));

    io.on('connection', (socket) => {
        socket.emit('curr_news', store.getState().toJS());
        socket.on('action', store.dispatch.bind(store));
    });
}
```

As you can see the action is what the client emits and the server makes an appropriate request when it receives the necessary action after which it emits the current state. The following is a sample reducer file

```
export default function reducer(curr_feeds = CURRENT_FEEDS, action) {
         switch (action.type) {
          case 'GET_TEST1DATA':
            return getTest1data(curr_feeds);
          case 'GET_TEST2DATA':
            return getTest2data(curr_feeds);
        }
}
```

here getTest1data and getTest2data essentially return a promise as it makes a request to some third part API. My problem is that as the the socket emits the curr_news immediately due to which the value of store.getState() is undefined.

My question is how do I make the store to observe and emit the socket once the promise resolves and not before that? Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you subscribe to the store you gain a state whenever it updates. If that new state is a promise, you could process that:

```
Store.subscribe(state => state.then(promisedData => io.emit(promisedData))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I get Cannot read property 'then' of undefined. Should I add something in the code so that the state is defined.

Comment: I changed my code to  `store.subscribe(
            () => {
                store.getState().then(data => io.emit('curr_news', data.toJS()));
            }
        )` and it worked for me